# Calling javascript function from MainActivity.java

Tags: javascript, android-studio

I want to call a javascript function from MainActivity.java in android studio which will set filename in localstorage to use it later. But without any webview call.

This is the structure of my project

[image]

Please suggest the best option. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Looks like you are using cordova. Editing generated file is generally not a good idea.

Comment: yes I'm using cordova. I want to save a file name from MainActivity.java on local storage so that I can show it on an html file which is in the assets > www folder.